# How to prevent watched videos to be listed in suggestions

Tags: youtube

In YouTube, it just happens that, older watched videos keep popping up in suggestions, when watching a particular video.

Is there anyway to prevent suggestion of already watched videos?

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no way to stop that.

The suggested videos that you see are the videos that are related to videos you have already watched.

Comment: I see, perhaps this could be a feature request to Youtube.